# Use COALESCE with Group by

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a single table which contains data like the following

```
pid     category name           subcategoryname
--------------------------------------------------------
424 Bathing & Infant Care   Baby Lotion
428 Bathing & Infant Care   Baby Lotion
445 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Accessories
337 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Accessories
69  Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Accessories
143 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Accessories
147 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Accessories
213 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Accessories
270 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Accessories
197 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Toys
390 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Toys
396 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Toys
416 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Toys
361 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Tub
447 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Tub
464 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Tub
491 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Tub
204 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Tub
286 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Tub
237 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Tub
240 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Tub
248 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Tub
148 Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Tub
23  Bathing & Infant Care   Bath Tub
153 Bathing & Infant Care   Humidifier
485 Bathing & Infant Care   Humidifier
14  Bathing & Infant Care   Other
64  Bathing & Infant Care   Other
73  Bathing & Infant Care   Shampoo & Body Wash
449 Bathing & Infant Care   Towels
```

The desired result is i need to write a sql script where i pass category name and output should be

```
subcategoryname | total count of records | comma separated list of pid
```

so if i pass "Bathing & Infant care" to my SQL, it should give me

```
subcategoryname totalcount pid
--------------------------------
Baby Lotion     2          424,428
Other           2          14,64
Baby Accesso    7          445,337,69,143,147,213,270
```

Comment: format your output please

Comment: formatted. please check now

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of the question title "Use COALESCE with Group by". I don't see any reference to COALESCE in neither the question nor the accepted answer. Please review the title.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to use `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF` to get the result:

```
select subcategoryname, count(*) total,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + cast(t2.pid as varchar(50))
          FROM yt t2
          where t.categoryname = t2.categoryname
            and t.subcategoryname = t2.subcategoryname
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS pid
from yt t
group by categoryname, subcategoryname;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a544b/6). Gives a result:

```
|     SUBCATEGORYNAME | TOTAL |                                                   PID |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         Baby Lotion |     2 |                                              424, 428 |
|    Bath Accessories |     7 |                      445, 337, 69, 143, 147, 213, 270 |
|           Bath Toys |     4 |                                    197, 390, 396, 416 |
|            Bath Tub |    11 |  361, 447, 464, 491, 204, 286, 237, 240, 248, 148, 23 |
|          Humidifier |     2 |                                              153, 485 |
|               Other |     2 |                                                14, 64 |
| Shampoo & Body Wash |     1 |                                                    73 |
|              Towels |     1 |                                                   449 |
```

Comment: +1 Excellent! I was just writing a similar answer myself (although not quite as comprehensive).

Comment: This answer is the way I'd do it, but if you have control over your database you may want to use http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/ to reduce complexity over time

Comment: how can i apply paging to my resultset, let say i just need 4 pids first time and later i need 5 to 8 then 9 to 13 etc..

Comment: @jatin Please post a new question with the details needed to answer. It will be too difficult to ask/answer a question in the comments.

Comment: @barlop If you're getting the value for variable, then yes [here is an example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/68092/9003). Otherwise, you'll need to use another method.

Comment: @Taryn You linked me to an answer that has two sets of code One that(like your answer), doesn't use Group By.  The other that doesn't use Coalesce. I'm asking based on the title of the question - Coalesce with group by.

Comment: @barlop You asked if it can be done with COALESCE, the answer is yes, if you're assigning it to a variable if not, then you need to use a method similar to my answer. Since the OP requested a table to be returned you can't use COALESCE.

Comment: @Taryn thanks, it may be worth addressing his title in your answer then.. that I suppose you can't use Coalesce with group by?

Comment: +1 Excellent!!!!! I found many answers from different posts but found this is the perfect one  THANKS!!.