# Group columns in query

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a query where I fetch the following columns:

```
ID       Name       Age       Hobby
```

`ID`, `name` and `age` comes from `Table A`
`Hobby` comes from `Table B`

Example of results I can get is the following:

```
ID       Name       Age       Hobby
0        John       35        Fishing
0        John       35        Tennis
0        John       35        Hiking
1        Jane       31        Fishing
2        Nate       42        Fishing
2        Nate       42        Tennis
```

**What I would like to have as result is the following instead:**

```
ID       Name       Age       Hobby
0        John       35        Fishing, Tennis, Hiking
1        Jane       31        Fishing
2        Nate       42        Fishing, Tennis
```

Any ideas of how to achieve that?

Comment: Use Coalesce or Stuff (as https://stackoverflow.com/a/16922374/1662973)

Comment: Please share table structure of table A and table B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT ID,NAME,AGE
    FROM TableName
)
SELECT *,
     STUFF(SELECT ','+ Hobby FROM TableName t1 WHERE t1.ID=CTE.ID FOR XML PATH(''),1,1,'')
FROM CTE
```